# Is there any init method given for struts2 action class?

Tags: java, struts2

Is there any init method provided for struts 2 action class that can be called before every method of that action class?

For example, I have an action class for struts 2 as given below

```
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;

public class EmployeeAction extends ActionSupport{

    private  DepartmentDaoService deptService = new DepartmentDaoService() ;
    private  EmployeeDaoService empService = new EmployeeDaoService();
    private Employee employee;
    private List<Employee> employees;
    private List<Department> departments;

       public void init()
       {
          //Do initialization stuff here
       }

       public String getAllEmployees(){
          employees = empService.getAllEmployees();
          return "success";
       }

       public String deleteEmployee(){
        empService.deleteEmployee(employee.getEmployeeId());
        return "success";
       }
}
```

Now in above code when struts action for `getAllEmployees()` and `deleteEmplyee()` is called I want `init()` method to execute first. We can run it by calling it from both functions.

But is there any provision given in struts 2 that will run init method automatically on each call or struts 2 provides any such method for action clases?

Please tell me if anyone knows.

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes there is:

First of all, your action class must implement the [Preparable interface](https://struts.apache.org/getting-started/preperable-interface.html). Then, your action must implement Preparable.prepare() method. Struts 2 will execute prepare() everytime before it invokes your action method.

Cheers.

Answer (score 8):

Take a look at the [Preparable interface and the Prepare Interceptor](https://struts.apache.org/getting-started/preperable-interface.html).

Comment: Links are broken. Refer to https://struts.apache.org/getting-started/preperable-interface.html

Answer (score 1):

Prepare Interceptor is way to go. If your action is using default interceptor stack just rename your `init()` method to **`prepare()`**.

If your action class has multiple action methods (like createEmployee() or deleteEmployee()) you can do specific preparation for concrete method with method named `prepare<*ActionMethodName*>()` (eg **`prepareDeleteEmployee()`**).

Answer (score 0):

Yes

```
init()
```

Called after an interceptor is created, but before any requests are processed using intercept , giving the Interceptor a chance to initialize any needed resources.

[See this](http://struts.apache.org/2.0.6/struts2-core/apidocs/com/opensymphony/xwork2/interceptor/Interceptor.html)